# Destroy all sub-components when routing to a parent route

Tags: angular, routes, components, parent-child, rerender

I have an application wherein I have my parent route which redirects to a child route in which the entire view loads.
Here I have many components which get the data from server and render it.

Based on certain conditions, I am redirecting to the parent route with different parameters. Again child route gets loaded with refreshed data which was passed to it.

```
parent ---> child -------------------Components getting data from Server ----
   <-----Different params------------
```

However in the child route, there are certain component which are still displaying old data. Usually they fetch the data from server to render it.

It seems to me that they were not destroyed when rerouted to parent route and hence are rendered using old data instead of getting data from server.

Any suggestion regarding what might be the problem ?

**Edit:**

It seems this was not the issue. The components are properly destroyed when re-routed. The issue is with the services which are not re-created.

[Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311713/angular-resetting-the-state-of-services-when-lazy-loaded-module-reloads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The services will not be recreated because they are singleton instances by default.

According documentation of the Angular:

> Services are singletons within the scope of an injector. There is at
>   most one instance of a service in a given injector.
>
> There is only one root injector, and the UserService is registered
>   with that injector. Therefore, there can be just one UserService
>   instance in the entire app, and every class that injects UserService
>   get this service instance.
>
> However, Angular DI is a hierarchical injection system, which means
>   that nested injectors can create their own service instances. Angular
>   creates nested injectors all the time

#### Solution:

If you really want to create a new instance of the services in each component, you must declare a provider for them at definition of the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child2',
  templateUrl: './child2.component.html',

  // create a new instance of the service
  providers: [AngularService]
})
```

> Component injectors are independent of each other and each of them
>   creates its own instances of the component-provided services.
>
> ...
>
> When Angular destroys one of these component instances, it also
>   destroys the component's injector and that injector's service
>   instances.

See this example that illustrate the injection of services in a Angular application: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-injecton-test

Documentation of Angular:

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#singleton-services

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to something like :

```
/showMeSomething/[id]
```

Angular knows that this id changed, so it reload's it's data (ngOnInit). But when your address is still :

```
/showMeSomething
```

it's still the same address every time you enter. So no new data is getting there (no ngOnInit).

Do you use something to keep your components alive?

There is a little bit complicated solution for this : you have to create a singleton service for your project and imprt it to parent and child component. Add over there a boolean to define if you want to reload child data. Then do something like that :

```
navigateToChildComponent(){
  this.mySingleton.reload = true;
  this.router.navigate['blabla/mycomponent'];
}
```

And there add something ngDoCheck - it works all the time.

```
ngDoCheck(){
  if(this.mySingleton.reload){
    this.mySingleton.reload = false;
    this.getMyData();
  } 
}
```

But still tell me if you use something to keep components alive in your project, and how you use it.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Comment: No I am not using anything to keep the components alive. Initially /auth/:id1/:id2/:id3 Is loaded. This redirects to another component which is the container for the functionalities. Now depending upon condition, I will want to reload above url with different values. I was hoping that since we have redirected to /auth/... hence all the components present inside Container will be destroyed and when I redirect again then it will be loaded with fresh values.