# Angular : Resetting the state of services when Lazy Loaded Module reloads

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-services, angular-module

I have the following structure in my application with respect to Services-

```
AppModule (AppComponent and HomeComponent)
|       |      |
Lazy1 Lazy2  Lazy3
```

My App starts with AppComponent which redirects to HomeComponent which then redirects to one of the Sub-Modules.

All submodules are lazy loaded. Now I start with AppComponent from where I am redirected to one of the Sub-Modules. Now depending on some condition, I am navigating back to HomeComponent which then again redirects to one of the sub-module.

My Problem is that if I again reload any of the Sub-Module with different data then also the **services of that sub-module will have same old data.** Essentially the services are not recreated as they should due to child injection.

*Need help to identify the issue here.*

**Additional Information -**

I have a few common services at App level in AppModule. Then each of the sub-module have a number of services which that module consumes. The app level services are injected in the sub-module services.

Comment: Add services that needs to be re-created to the "providers" list of lazily loaded modules.  Normally, services declared in app module are singleton and shared between all components - irrespective of whether eagerly loaded or lazily loaded.  If services are declared again in lazily loaded modules, then, they get a new instance of service

Comment: Did that only but still the state is maintained.

Comment: Okay - I think that is expected as service instances are still around.  Typically, one does some kind of server API call to get new data in ngInit of component which will update the service state.  Not sure what is your design.

Comment: In my service, I store the data received from server. If data is available then we will not hit server again for same transaction. If another one is loaded then we need new data for that one.

Comment: Can we not destroy and recreate the services ?

Comment: I don't think so - they are singleton and will live forever.   If you are maintaining state in service, you may have to keep them updated.

Comment: If I provide a service in a component's provider array then it is destroyed with component. But if I provide it in some lazy loaded module then wouldn't it be destroyed with that module ?

Comment: Hmm...AFAIK lazy loaded modules are loaded when they are requested for first time - after that, they just stay around.

Comment: It's 2024 and I just want to re-iterate @WandMaker 's comments as some strict set of rules - I'm doing a lot of cleanup on a project due to not knowing this.

1. Any data that should react to component lifecycle needs to live on the component. This includes services, if they should reset with the component, provide them at the top of the component not in a module (lazy or not).

2. Lazy loaded means it waits until first use to load, rather that when the whole app bootstraps. Modules have no lifecycle, they do not get destroyed once loaded - and same applies to services provided in them.